# if sonar lint is integrated with sonarQube then Rules will be taken from SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

i have integrated sonarLint with sonarQube. In my eclipse i can see the issues after analysis.
I wanted to know the rules are taken from sonarQube or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I depends on whether or not you have bound to the SonarQube  Server.

You can check this by right clicking on the project => Sonar Lint => Bind to a SonarQube project.

If you bind to it then the rules will be used from the SonarQube.